# Загруженность системного диска C на 100% на ОС Win 10

Tags: windows, администрирование, windows-10

Время от времени на диске C: спонтанно возникает 100% нагрузка.

Данный диск имеет объем 1ТБ и разбит на 2 раздела:

1. 200ГБ под систему
2. 800ГБ для файловой помойки.

В момент нагрузки ни на одном из разделов мною не производится никаких ресурсоемких действий и в фоне ничего нет (например, торрентов).

На этом диске стоит MS SQL, но использую я его для разработки, и извне никто не работает с ним, и, на мой взгляд, он не может быть причиной проблем.

Проверял антивирусом и ничего не нашел.

Делал дефрагментацию обоих разделов, а также проверял на ошибки, но улучшений я не заметил.

CrystalDiskInfo никаких ошибок в S.M.A.R.T не находит.

С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Имело бы смысл проверить диск какой-нибудь программой вроде Victoria, т.к. это очень похоже то что какой-то сектор на диске плохо читается, но всё еще читается, поэтому когда система пытается что-то из него прочитать она "подвисает" со 100% нагрузкой, но в СМАРТе это пока еще не отображается, т.к. ремапов и ошибок по факту еще нет.

Comment: А если взять что-нибудь посвежее, например Acronis?

Comment: Думаю неважно, главное чтобы проверяла именно физическую читабельность секторов и показывала задержки при чтении. Я просто привык к вике :)

Comment: @Alekcvp, а можно узнать из какого раздела идет такая нагрузка?

Comment: Надо весь диск проверять.

Comment: Из моих личных наблюдений, SQL Server (используется тоже только для разработки) периодически сильно грузит и процессор, и диск. Чем он в это время занят - чёрт его знает. Когда он слишком досаждает, я просто убиваю его процесс. При необходимости - запускаю.

Comment: @iluxa1810 это ж 10-я винда. Со времен висты в винду встроен монитор диска, который показывает кто, что и куда пишет. Ctrl+Shift+Esc / закладка Performance/Open Resource Monitor

Comment: Вопросы, не имеющие прямого отношения к программированию или системному администрированию - оффтопик на SO. Это вопрос пользовательского уровня, без шагов для воспроизведения, и ответы на него будут **советами** по использованию утилит (или, еще хуже, ответами в стиле "это софтина X ест, убей ее!"), а не полноценными ответами, решающими проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй с помощью утилиты [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) отследить, какая из программ пишет и читает с диска в настоящий момент.

Когда запустишь, установи фильтр в положение «Отслеживать только операции с диском», как на скриншоте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: (Оффтоп). Пожалуйста, постарайтесь не использовать комментарии, содержащие негативную коннотацию, вроде [**«убрал воду»**](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/144696). Они могут быть обидны для адресата, способствовать созданию недоброжелательной атмосферы. См. [**http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/4488/199934**](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/4488/199934). Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных ok/ принято.

Answer (score -1):

Попробовать монитором ресурсов определить «жруна» по диску. После уже профайлером или файлмонитором по процессу глянуть, что именно пытается считать/записать. Уже по результатам решать, что делать.